# ./configure cannot not find a working compiler while building gmp library with MSYS2

Tags: build, configure, gmp

I'm trying to build gmp-6.1.2 on Windows using MSYS2 with `./configure --enable-cxx` command. I get the following error:

> configure: error: could not find a working compiler, see config.log for details

Below is the content of `config.log`

```
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by GNU MP configure 6.1.2, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.69.  Invocation command line was

  $ ./configure --enable-cxx

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = computer-name
uname -m = x86_64
uname -r = 2.11.1(0.329/5/3)
uname -s = MINGW64_NT-10.0
uname -v = 2018-09-10 14:19

/usr/bin/uname -p = unknown
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = x86_64
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = unknown
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /mingw64/bin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /c/Windows/System32
PATH: /c/Windows
PATH: /c/Windows/System32/Wbem
PATH: /c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/
PATH: /usr/bin/site_perl
PATH: /usr/bin/vendor_perl
PATH: /usr/bin/core_perl


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:2885: loading site script /mingw64/etc/config.site
| # This file is in public domain.
| # Original author: Karlson2k (Evgeny Grin)
| # Written for MSys2/MinGW64 to help running 'configure' scripts
| 
| # Defaults for MinGW64-targeted programs
| 
| # Set proper selfname on bash and fallback to default name on other shells
| test -n "${BASH_SOURCE}" 2>/dev/null && config_site_me="${BASH_SOURCE[0]##*/}" || config_site_me=config.site
| 
| # Set default 'host' to speedup configure
| if test -z "$build_alias"; then
|   build_alias="${MSYSTEM_CHOST-x86_64-w64-mingw32}" && \
|     $as_echo "$config_site_me:${as_lineno-$LINENO}: default build_alias set to $build_alias" >&5 
| fi
| 
| # Set default 'prefix' to "/mingw64"
| if ( test -z "$prefix" || test "x$prefix" = "xNONE" ) && \
|    ( test -z "$exec_prefix" || test "x$exec_prefix" = "xNONE" ); then
|   prefix="${MSYSTEM_PREFIX-/mingw64}" && \
|     $as_echo "$config_site_me:${as_lineno-$LINENO}: default prefix set to $prefix" >&5
| fi
config.site:13: default build_alias set to x86_64-w64-mingw32
config.site:20: default prefix set to /mingw64
configure:3055: checking build system type
configure:3069: result: x86_64-w64-mingw32
configure:3089: checking host system type
configure:3102: result: x86_64-w64-mingw32
configure:3139: checking for a BSD-compatible install
configure:3207: result: /usr/bin/install -c
configure:3218: checking whether build environment is sane
configure:3273: result: yes
configure:3424: checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p
configure:3463: result: /usr/bin/mkdir -p
configure:3470: checking for gawk
configure:3486: found /usr/bin/gawk
configure:3497: result: gawk
configure:3508: checking whether make sets $(MAKE)
configure:3534: result: no
configure:3559: checking whether make supports nested variables
configure:3576: result: no
configure:3705: checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles
configure:3714: result: no
User:
ABI=
CC=
CFLAGS=(unset)
CPPFLAGS=(unset)
MPN_PATH=
GMP:
abilist=64 x32 32
cclist=gcc icc cc
configure:5801: gcc 2>&1 | grep xlc >/dev/null
configure:5804: $? = 1
configure:5858: checking compiler gcc -O2 -pedantic -fomit-frame-pointer -m64 
Test compile: 
configure:5872: gcc -O2 -pedantic -fomit-frame-pointer -m64  conftest.c >&5
./configure: line 5873: gcc: command not found
configure:5875: $? = 127
failed program was:

int main () { return 0; }
configure:6962: result: no
configure:5779: cc -c conftest.c >&5
./configure: line 5780: cc: command not found
configure:5782: $? = 127
configure:5801: cc 2>&1 | grep xlc >/dev/null
configure:5804: $? = 1
configure:5858: checking compiler cc -O 
Test compile: 
configure:5872: cc -O  conftest.c >&5
./configure: line 5873: cc: command not found
configure:5875: $? = 127
failed program was:

int main () { return 0; }
configure:6962: result: no
configure:5801: gcc 2>&1 | grep xlc >/dev/null
configure:5804: $? = 1
configure:5858: checking compiler gcc -O2 -pedantic -fomit-frame-pointer -mx32 
Test compile: 
configure:5872: gcc -O2 -pedantic -fomit-frame-pointer -mx32  conftest.c >&5
./configure: line 5873: gcc: command not found
configure:5875: $? = 127
failed program was:

int main () { return 0; }
configure:6962: result: no
configure:5779: cc -c conftest.c >&5
./configure: line 5780: cc: command not found
configure:5782: $? = 127
configure:5801: cc 2>&1 | grep xlc >/dev/null
configure:5804: $? = 1
configure:5858: checking compiler cc  
Test compile: 
configure:5872: cc   conftest.c >&5
./configure: line 5873: cc: command not found
configure:5875: $? = 127
failed program was:

int main () { return 0; }
configure:6962: result: no
configure:5801: gcc 2>&1 | grep xlc >/dev/null
configure:5804: $? = 1
configure:5858: checking compiler gcc -m32 -O2 -pedantic -fomit-frame-pointer 
Test compile: 
configure:5872: gcc -m32 -O2 -pedantic -fomit-frame-pointer  conftest.c >&5
./configure: line 5873: gcc: command not found
configure:5875: $? = 127
failed program was:

int main () { return 0; }
configure:6962: result: no
configure:5858: checking compiler gcc -O2 -pedantic -fomit-frame-pointer 
Test compile: 
configure:5872: gcc -O2 -pedantic -fomit-frame-pointer  conftest.c >&5
./configure: line 5873: gcc: command not found
configure:5875: $? = 127
failed program was:

int main () { return 0; }
configure:6962: result: no
configure:5779: icc -c conftest.c >&5
./configure: line 5780: icc: command not found
configure:5782: $? = 127
configure:5801: icc 2>&1 | grep xlc >/dev/null
configure:5804: $? = 1
configure:5858: checking compiler icc -no-gcc 
Test compile: 
configure:5872: icc -no-gcc  conftest.c >&5
./configure: line 5873: icc: command not found
configure:5875: $? = 127
failed program was:

int main () { return 0; }
configure:6962: result: no
configure:5779: cc -c conftest.c >&5
./configure: line 5780: cc: command not found
configure:5782: $? = 127
configure:5801: cc 2>&1 | grep xlc >/dev/null
configure:5804: $? = 1
configure:5858: checking compiler cc -O 
Test compile: 
configure:5872: cc -O  conftest.c >&5
./configure: line 5873: cc: command not found
configure:5875: $? = 127
failed program was:

int main () { return 0; }
configure:6962: result: no
configure:7200: error: could not find a working compiler, see config.log for details

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_build=x86_64-w64-mingw32
ac_cv_env_ABI_set=
ac_cv_env_ABI_value=
ac_cv_env_CCC_set=
ac_cv_env_CCC_value=
ac_cv_env_CC_FOR_BUILD_set=
ac_cv_env_CC_FOR_BUILD_value=
ac_cv_env_CC_set=
ac_cv_env_CC_value=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPP_FOR_BUILD_set=
ac_cv_env_CPP_FOR_BUILD_value=
ac_cv_env_CPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CPP_value=
ac_cv_env_CXXCPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CXXCPP_value=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CXX_set=
ac_cv_env_CXX_value=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_LT_SYS_LIBRARY_PATH_set=
ac_cv_env_LT_SYS_LIBRARY_PATH_value=
ac_cv_env_M4_set=
ac_cv_env_M4_value=
ac_cv_env_YACC_set=
ac_cv_env_YACC_value=
ac_cv_env_YFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_YFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
ac_cv_host=x86_64-w64-mingw32
ac_cv_path_install='/usr/bin/install -c'
ac_cv_path_mkdir=/usr/bin/mkdir
ac_cv_prog_AWK=gawk
ac_cv_prog_make_make_set=no
am_cv_make_support_nested_variables=no

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

ABI=''
ACLOCAL='${SHELL} /c/Users/x/Desktop/gmp-6.1.2/missing aclocal-1.15'
AMTAR='$${TAR-tar}'
AM_BACKSLASH='\'
AM_DEFAULT_V='1'
AM_DEFAULT_VERBOSITY='1'
AM_V='1'
AR=''
AS=''
ASMFLAGS=''
AUTOCONF='${SHELL} /c/Users/x/Desktop/gmp-6.1.2/missing autoconf'
AUTOHEADER='${SHELL} /c/Users/x/Desktop/gmp-6.1.2/missing autoheader'
AUTOMAKE='${SHELL} /c/Users/x/Desktop/gmp-6.1.2/missing automake-1.15'
AWK='gawk'
CALLING_CONVENTIONS_OBJS='x86call.lo x86check$U.lo'
CC=''
CCAS=''
CC_FOR_BUILD=''
CFLAGS=''
CPP=''
CPPFLAGS=''
CPP_FOR_BUILD=''
CXX=''
CXXCPP=''
CXXFLAGS=''
CYGPATH_W='cygpath -w'
DEFN_LONG_LONG_LIMB=''
DEFS=''
DLLTOOL=''
DSYMUTIL=''
DUMPBIN=''
ECHO_C=''
ECHO_N='-n'
ECHO_T=''
EGREP=''
ENABLE_STATIC_FALSE=''
ENABLE_STATIC_TRUE=''
EXEEXT=''
EXEEXT_FOR_BUILD=''
FGREP=''
GMP_LDFLAGS=''
GMP_LIMB_BITS=''
GMP_NAIL_BITS='0'
GREP=''
HAVE_CLOCK_01=''
HAVE_CPUTIME_01=''
HAVE_GETRUSAGE_01=''
HAVE_GETTIMEOFDAY_01=''
HAVE_HOST_CPU_FAMILY_power='0'
HAVE_HOST_CPU_FAMILY_powerpc='0'
HAVE_SIGACTION_01=''
HAVE_SIGALTSTACK_01=''
HAVE_SIGSTACK_01=''
HAVE_STACK_T_01=''
HAVE_SYS_RESOURCE_H_01=''
INSTALL_DATA='${INSTALL} -m 644'
INSTALL_PROGRAM='${INSTALL}'
INSTALL_SCRIPT='${INSTALL}'
INSTALL_STRIP_PROGRAM='$(install_sh) -c -s'
LD=''
LDFLAGS=''
LEX=''
LEXLIB=''
LEX_OUTPUT_ROOT=''
LIBCURSES=''
LIBGMPXX_LDFLAGS=''
LIBGMP_DLL=''
LIBGMP_LDFLAGS=''
LIBM=''
LIBM_FOR_BUILD=''
LIBOBJS=''
LIBREADLINE=''
LIBS=''
LIBTOOL=''
LIPO=''
LN_S=''
LTLIBOBJS=''
LT_SYS_LIBRARY_PATH=''
M4=''
MAINT='#'
MAINTAINER_MODE_FALSE=''
MAINTAINER_MODE_TRUE='#'
MAKEINFO='${SHELL} /c/Users/x/Desktop/gmp-6.1.2/missing makeinfo'
MANIFEST_TOOL=''
MKDIR_P='/usr/bin/mkdir -p'
NM=''
NMEDIT=''
OBJDUMP=''
OBJEXT=''
OTOOL64=''
OTOOL=''
PACKAGE='gmp'
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT='gmp-bugs@gmplib.org, see https://gmplib.org/manual/Reporting-Bugs.html'
PACKAGE_NAME='GNU MP'
PACKAGE_STRING='GNU MP 6.1.2'
PACKAGE_TARNAME='gmp'
PACKAGE_URL='http://www.gnu.org/software/gmp/'
PACKAGE_VERSION='6.1.2'
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
RANLIB=''
SED=''
SET_MAKE='MAKE=make'
SHELL='/bin/sh'
SPEED_CYCLECOUNTER_OBJ='pentium.lo'
STRIP=''
TAL_OBJECT=''
TUNE_LIBS=''
TUNE_SQR_OBJ=''
U_FOR_BUILD=''
VERSION='6.1.2'
WANT_CXX_FALSE=''
WANT_CXX_TRUE=''
WITH_READLINE_01=''
YACC=''
YFLAGS=''
ac_ct_AR=''
ac_ct_CC=''
ac_ct_CXX=''
ac_ct_DUMPBIN=''
am__EXEEXT_FALSE=''
am__EXEEXT_TRUE=''
am__isrc=''
am__leading_dot='.'
am__tar='$${TAR-tar} chof - "$$tardir"'
am__untar='$${TAR-tar} xf -'
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build='x86_64-w64-mingw32'
build_alias='x86_64-w64-mingw32'
build_cpu='x86_64'
build_os='mingw32'
build_vendor='w64'
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE_TARNAME}'
dvidir='${docdir}'
exec_prefix='NONE'
gmp_srclinks=''
host='x86_64-w64-mingw32'
host_alias=''
host_cpu='x86_64'
host_os='mingw32'
host_vendor='w64'
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
install_sh='${SHELL} /c/Users/x/Desktop/gmp-6.1.2/install-sh'
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
mkdir_p='$(MKDIR_P)'
mpn_objects=''
mpn_objs_in_libgmp=''
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
pdfdir='${docdir}'
prefix='/mingw64'
program_transform_name='s,x,x,'
psdir='${docdir}'
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target_alias=''

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

/* confdefs.h */
#define PACKAGE_NAME "GNU MP"
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME "gmp"
#define PACKAGE_VERSION "6.1.2"
#define PACKAGE_STRING "GNU MP 6.1.2"
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "gmp-bugs@gmplib.org, see https://gmplib.org/manual/Reporting-Bugs.html"
#define PACKAGE_URL "http://www.gnu.org/software/gmp/"
#define PACKAGE "gmp"
#define VERSION "6.1.2"
#define WANT_FFT 1
#define HAVE_HOST_CPU_x86_64 1
#define HOST_DOS64 1

configure: exit 1
```

Definitely, `$CC` is empty. I have gcc installed with MinGW so I tried to assign `/c/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe` to `$CC` but that didn't work either.

I know there are similar questions but none of those solutions solves my problem.

Comment: I believe msys2 comes with a package manager, that has a package for GMP. Is there a particular reason why you are trying to build it yourself?

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know it gmp is installed along with MSYS. I searched and found the gmp folder which contains only 4 files - desc, files, install, mtree. So how should I use these now?